# Grunt - Watch Task is not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

It seems like my watch task in my project grunt file is starting up then quitting straight away.

Please review the screenshot attached.

Please find the code for my Gruntfile.js;

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            options: {
                cacheLocation: '.sass-cache'
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: [{
                    'assets/css/dist/main.min.css': 'assets/css/sass/main.scss'
                }]
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    style: 'nested'
                },
                files: [{
                    'assets/css/main.css': 'assets/css/sass/main.scss'
                }]
            }
        },
        imageoptim: {
          files: [
            'img/flat',
            'img/flat/**'
          ],
          options: {
            imageAlpha: true,
            jpegMini: true,
            quitAfter: true
          }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
              mangle: true,
              compress: true
            },
            jsCompress: {
                files: {
                    'js/dist/main.min.js': ['js/src/script1.js', 'js/src/script2.js']
            }
          }
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
          },
          dist: {
                src: ['js/src/script1.js', 'js/src/script2.js'],
                dest: 'js/dist/main.min.js',
          }
        },
        watch: {
            sassWatch: {
                files: 'css/sass/**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass:prod', 'sass:dev'],
            },
            JsWatch: {
                files: ['js/modules/script1.js', 'js/modules/script2.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify:jsCompress', 'concat:dist'],
            }
        },
        notify: {
            sassNotify: {
                options: {
                    title: "Task Complete",
                    message: "Your Sass has been compiled and concatanatated!"
                }
            },
            jsNotify: {
                options: {
                    title: "Task Complete",
                    message: "Your JS has been minified and concatanatated!"
                }
            },
            imageNotify: {
                options: {
                    title: "Task Complete",
                    message: "All images have been compressed"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-imageoptim');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');

    grunt.registerTask('sassNotify', 'watch:sassWatch');
    grunt.registerTask('jsNotify', 'watch:jsWatch');
    grunt.registerTask('imageNotify', 'imageoptim');

};
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Kind Regards,

B!

[image]

Comment: JsWatch and jsWatch are two different things.  Does that difference also exist in your gruntfile?  I don't think it is causing your problem though, I think the answer about updating watch is your first port of call.

Comment: 1. stolen from grunt [api](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task)

        The taskList argument must be an array of tasks.

2. can you verify that files changes trigger the task?i.e with inserting new line and save it. 

3. AFAIK specify task on watch which **not exist** will not throw an error.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that it was watching to much i had 100+ image files that it was keeping track of so i just specified what it should watch (js, html, scss, css).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the issue and was looking for an answer.  In my case I had a typo in my `files:` matching pattern which caused it to not find the directory to watch and abort, although an error message would have been nice.  I notice that in your `sass` task you prepend your files with`assets/` but not in your watch task.

I understand you've likely moved on but hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
   ....

    watch: {
        dev: {
            files: 'assets/sass/**/*{.scss,.js}',
            tasks: ['sass:dev','uglify:jsCompress'],
        },

    },

    ...

});

grunt.registerTask('dev', 'watch:dev');
```

The [watch task in my gruntfile](https://github.com/pburtchaell/site/blob/master/gruntfile.js#L294) may be helpful.

Comment: Could you either update the link or just post your gruntfile in the answer Patrick? Would have loved to see the whole file :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this was not working as expected with an older version of `grunt-contrib-watch`. In my case, I was using `grunt-contrib-watch` V0.4.4.

Try updating the `grunt-contrib-watch` package to the latest version, by running:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch@latest --save-dev
```

and then try execute your task again.

Answer (score -3):

Here is how my Gruntfile.js looks like and it works ok:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {                              // Task
            dist: {                            // Target
                options: {                       // Target options
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {                         // Dictionary of files
                    'css/styles.css': './sass/site.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            },
            organic: {
                files: ['../organic-css/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch']);

}
```

Maybe you need to register a "default" tasks.